# How can I convert defaultdict(Set) to defaultdict(list)?

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have a `defaultdict(Set)`:

```
from sets import Set
from collections import defaultdict
values = defaultdict(Set)
```

I want the Set functionality when building it up in order to remove duplicates. Next step I want to store this as json. Since json doesn't support this datastructure I would like to convert the datastructure into a `defaultdict(list)` but when I try:

```
defaultdict(list)(values)
```

I get: `TypeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object is not callable`, how should I do the conversion?

Comment: `from sets import Set` - Python has an improved `set` type now that you don't need to import. You should stop using the old `sets.Set`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use following:

```
>>> values = defaultdict(Set)
>>> values['a'].add(1)
>>> defaultdict(list, ((k, list(v)) for k, v in values.items()))
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1]})
```

[`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) constructor takes `default_factory` as a first argument which can be followed by the same arguments as in normal `dict`. In this case the second argument is a generator expression that returns tuples consisting key and value.

Note that if you only need to store it as a JSON normal `dict` will do just fine:

```
 >>> {k: list(v) for k, v in values.items()}
 {'a': [1]}
```

Comment: jonalv might not need the defaultdict functionality here. You could use an even simpler dict comprehension:
 `new_values = {k: list(v) for k, v in values.items()}`

Answer (score 3):

```
defaultdict(list, values)
```

The defaultdict constructor works like the dict constructor with a mandatory `default_factory` argument in front. However, this won't convert any existing values from Sets to lists. If you want to do that, you need to do it manually:

```
defaultdict(list, ((k, list(v)) for k, v in values.viewitems()))
```

You might not even want a defaultdict at all at that point, though:

```
{k: list(v) for k, v in values.viewitems()}
```

Comment: This will leave the each existing entry as a `set`.

Comment: @JaredGoguen: Yeah, I was in the middle of editing to address that.

Answer (score 0):

Say that `a = set()`, and you have populated it already with unique values. Then, when using `defaultdict` you could cast it into a list: `defaultdict(list(a))`