# Tagging simlar products together using python

Tags: python, pandas

Based on 3 keys/columns uniqueid , uniqueid2 and uniqueid3, I need to generate a column new_key that will tag all associated rows with a single key.

For tagging products same, we need to compare all the 3 columns iteratively in dataset. For eg. first row when compared with all other rows dont have similarity based on any of the columns. But for 2nd row if we compare that with 3rd row it has same uniqueid/uniqueid2. so, they are tagged as uniqueid for starting row. Now in 4th row Uniqueid3 matches. so, its also tagged together. so, one we need to compare each row with every other.

```py
  df = pd.DataFrame({'uniqueid': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 
                                   4: 'd', 5: 'd', 6: 'e', 7: 'e',8:'g',9:'g',10:'h',11:'l',12:'m'},
'uniqueid2': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 
                                   4: 'd', 5: 'd', 6: 'e', 7: 'e',8:'g',9:'g',10:'h',11:'l',12:'l'},
                      'uniqueid3': {0: 'z', 1: 'y', 2: 'x', 3: 'y', 
                                    4: 'x', 5: 'v', 6: 'x', 7: 'u',8:'h',9:'i',10:'k',11:'k',12:'n'}})
```

Data that I have based on columns uniqueid ,uniqueid2 and uniqueid3. I need to create new_key as already there. Here in this dummy data all the rows except first belong to a same product based on associations in column 1 and column2.

But I am unsure on how to proceed further. Quick help needed please

Expected Output

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how you generate `new_key`, can you explain further?

Comment: Added information on how I am generating new_key. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to build a dict and have two nested loops, each row, then each key:set_values.

```
# build a dictionary that contains the new keys and the unique values it refers to
# initialize with the first row
# and use numbers for keys, so we can +=1 later on
newkeys = {1: set(df.iloc[0].values)}
key_col = []
nextkey = 2

# loop df rows without the index
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    # and get unique row values
    rowset = set(row)

    # see if the row can be tagged with an existing newkey
    for key, values in newkeys.items():
        # if there is a value that appears in a previous row then the intersection will not be empty
       if rowset & values:
            # exit the for loop and skip the else clause
            # current newkey will be selected for the row
            break

    else:
        # for loop exhausted without breaking
        # none of  rowset values appear in any previous key
        # then create a new key
        key = nextkey
        nextkey += 1

    # add values to the newkey and tag row
    newkeys[key].update(rowset)
    key_col.append(key)

# save to df
df['new_key'] = key_col
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic that you have written?

Comment: -THis is the error I am getting--------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fe6460329e23> in <module>
     35 
     36     # add values to the newkey and tag row
---> 37     newkeys[key].update(rowset)
     38     key_col.append(key)
     39 

KeyError: 2

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-46223af8e116> in <module>
     10 
     11 df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
---> 12 newkeys = defaultdict(set())
     13 
     14 key_col = []

NameError: name 'defaultdict' is not defined

Comment: `from collections import defaultdict`

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-c2f7f3ea2049> in <module>
     12 df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
     13 
---> 14 newkeys = defaultdict(set())
     15 
     16 key_col = []

TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

Comment: Sorry about the back and forth, but I'm om my phone... check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37212808/6692898)